# How to send text code of custom emoji to server with text from UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, emoji

I added a textview and assigned its delegate to the View Controller.

```
@IBOutlet var textview: UITextView!
var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textview.delegate = self
    attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString:textview.attributedText!)

}
```

I have a button which when clicked will add/append a custom emoji to the textview a `NSAttributedString` containing `NSTextAttachment` using following code.

```
@IBAction func actAngry(_ sender: Any) {
    let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
    attachment.image = UIImage(named: "Angry")

    let attributedEmoji = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
    attributedString.append(attributedEmoji)

    textview.attributedText = attributedString
}
```

Now when I'll click on send button and here i want to replace that custom emoji with some code e.g. `#43567`, this is custom code for the emoji.

```
@IBAction func sendNow(_ sender: Any) {
    print(textview.attributedText)
    print(textview.text)
}
```

So If a type `Hi, How are you?` and than press `actAngry` button. 
It will look like `Hi, How are you?[Angry Image]`.

[image: Textview with text and custom emoji]

It should convert to: `Hi, How are you?#43567`, so that i can send it to server.

What have I tried, I tried follwing delegate method to get some idea, but failed:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith textAttachment: NSTextAttachment, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
```

Comment: What if you can send something like this `Hi, How are you? :blush:` or `Hi, How are you? :grin:` to server?

Comment: But I have to show image for :blush: to the user while user inputs it, the custom code be anything, but primary concern is: "how to replace image with code?"

Comment: Yes you can do that too. I will post an answer.

Comment: I can convert "Hi, How are you? :blush:" to  "Hi, How are you? [Image here]", but my question is to do other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Found [THIS](https://github.com/safx/Emoji-Swift) amazing library to perform this task and to use that you need to add two files onto project listed below:

```
Emoji.swift 
String+Emoji.swift
```

Code is too much long So I can not paste it here.

Now you can use it this way when you want to send text to server:

```
let emojiWithString = "Hi, How are you? "
print(emojiWithString.emojiEscapedString)
```

This will print: `Hi, How are you? :grin:`

You can send this text to server now and when you receive same string from server you can convert string to emoji this way by using same library:

```
let str = "Hi, How are you? :grin:"
print(str.emojiUnescapedString)
```

And this will print:

```
Hi, How are you?
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Okay, I'll what it does. :)

Comment: Is that what you need?

Comment: it would be nice if someone will code for the Android version of this library.